# reactjs conditional component methods based on configuration object

Tags: function, coffeescript, reactjs

I'm setting up a sortable filterable table and I'm trying to make it so I can define objects on the component to build all the necessary functions.

I want to take this,

```
RailsTable = React.createClass
  mixins: [
    Backbone.React.Component.mixin
  ]

  setSearchTermFilter: (e)->
    search_term = e.target.value
    @setState(search_term: search_term)

  setGroupNumberFilter: (e)->
    rail_group = parseInt(e.target.value)
    @setState(rail_group: rail_group)

  setSystemNameFilter: (e)->
    system_name = e.target.value
    @setState(system_name: system_name)

  filteredResults: ->
    filteredResults = @getCollection()
    filteredResults = filteredResults.bySearchTerm(@state.search_term)
    filteredResults = filteredResults.byRailGroup(@state.rail_group)
    filteredResults = filteredResults.bySystemName(@state.system_name)

    filteredResults.sortDirection = @state.sortDirection
    filteredResults.sortBy(@state.sortAttribute)
    filteredResults



  render: ->
    blah
```

and make it into this,

```
RailsTable = React.createClass
  mixins: [
    Backbone.React.Component.mixin
    Evue.Mixins.FilterMixin
  ]

  filterTypes:
    'search_term'  : ''
    'system_name'  : ''
    'rail_group'   : 0

  render: ->
    blah
```

I think this is fine, but the trouble comes up in the mixin. I need to iterate over the filterTypes object and create functions based on that. So if I have search_term then I need a setSearchTermFilter function, but each table will have various attributes so I need them to be created based on what I enter.

Here's an idea of what I want, but doesn't work,

```
Evue.Mixins.FilterMixin =

  getInitialState: ->
    @searchTypes

  @filterTypes.each (filterObject)->
    setFilterObject: (newFilterObject)->
      @setState(filterObject: newFilterObject)
```

I don't even know if this is doable and I really think that I'm just approaching this wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's target this design.  The mixin is created specifically for the component, which allows it to be more dynamic (including having dynamic functions).

```
RailsTable = React.createClass
  mixins: [
    Backbone.React.Component.mixin
    Evue.Mixins.makeFilterMixin {
      'search_term'  : ''
      'system_name'  : ''
      'rail_group'   : 0
    }
  ]
  render: ->
    blah
```

First we must create this function, and get the names of the filters, both in the initial snake_case and in PascalCase.

```
Evue.Mixins.makeFilterMixin = (filters) ->
  mixin = {}
  filterNames = Object.keys filters
  filterNamesToPascal = {}

  filterNames.forEach (name) ->
    filterNamesToPascal[name] = pascalCase(name)
```

The initial state function is simple.

```
  mixin.getInitialState = ->
    state = {}
    for name in filterNames
      state[name] = filters[name]
    state
```

This is the first place we use the filterNamesToPascal.  filterFnName will be something like `"bySearchTerm"` for the search_term filter.  We then pass the state value to it, and continue filtering in a loop.

```
  mixin.filteredResults = ->
    filteredResults = @getCollection()
    for filter in filterNames
      filterFnName = "by" + filterNamesToPascal[filter]
      filteredResults = filteredResults[filterFnName](this.state[filter])

    filteredResults.sortDirection = @state.sortDirection
    filteredResults.sortBy(@state.sortAttribute)
    filteredResults
```

This is the main reason we need a function which returns a mixin.  To create functions like `setSearchTermFilter` on the fly, we need to set those directly on the mixin.  We use the default value's constructor to convert it back to the right type.  This works with primitive constructors like String and Number.  You give up the ability to enforce integers for number types.  To do that, you'd have to have a full featured schema.

```
  filterNames.forEach (name) ->
    constructor = filters[name]?.constructor || String
    mixin["set" + filterNamesToPascal[name] + "Filter"] = (e) ->
      update = {}
      update[name] = constructor e.target.value
      @setState update
  mixin
```

And finally, a simple utility function to do the snake_case to PascalCase.

```
pascalCase = (s) ->
  words = s.split("_").map (x) ->
    x[0].toUpperCase() + x.slice(1)
  words.join("")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So do I need to put the { search_term: '', rail_group: 0 } object into the mixin or can I leave it on the component? I pulled it off with it on the component, but I think you just did that for better code structure. Also I ended up creating functions 'setStringFilter' and 'setIntegerFilter'. This is probably safer for when I have future inputs of various types, right? Either way, thanks for the responses.

Comment: Also is it safe to translate strings into functions? I've heard that doing this can be unsafe, but I have no clue.

Comment: @BlaineHatab Yes you need to pass it to the mixin; I explained why.  Yes, there's always a trade off between simplicity and flexibility.  Strings aren't being translated into functions, they're being translated into property names.  In this case, they're not user provided and couldn't end up overriding something else leading to unexpected behavior or error, so it's safe.

Comment: Thank you once again. I'm still not 100% sure why you need to pass it into the mixin. The only reason I'm asking is that I am auto generating some html based off of the @filterTypes object on the component. I don't think I can do that if I pass it into the mixin though.

Comment: You can store the object in a variable and use it in multiple places.  And the reason you need to use it to create the mixin is because the functions the mixin provides depend on that object.